# Migration: Cannot add foreign key constraint - Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, migration, laravel-9

I'm trying to create foreign keys in Laravel however when I migrate my table using artisan i am thrown the following error:

```
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `bright`.`carts` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `carts` add constraint `carts_product_id_foreign` foreign key (`product_id`) references `products` (`id`) on delete cascade)
```

My migration code is as so: carts migration file

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('carts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('customer_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('customers')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('quantity');

    });

}
```

products migration file

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('unit');
        $table->decimal('price', 6, 3);
        $table->string('img_url');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->integer('sold');
        $table->integer('in_stock');
        
    });
}
```

customers migration file

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('phone_number');
        $table->string('address');
        $table->string('zip')->nullable();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('user_name')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
    });
}
```

Any ideas as to what I've done wrong, I want to get this right now, as I've got a lot of tables I need to create e.g. carts, products, customers. Ideally I want to create carts table which hold this data with the foreign keys, i..e product_id and cart_id

Comment: Your primary key is **big integer**, so your foreign key Should be `bigInteger` => `$table->bigInteger('product_id')->unsigned();` and  `$table->bigInteger('customer_id')->unsigned();`

Comment: Try what @sta has said and make foreign key 'nullable()'

Answer (score 0):

Try using this structure.

```
$table->foreignIdFor(Product::class);
$table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
$table->foreignIdFor(Customer::class);
$table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('customers');
```

Also make sure, your products and customers migrations run before your carts migrations, and your models are imported to your migrations.

Comment: that works perfectly! I couldn’t have done it without you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id')->nullable();
$table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('customer_id')->nullable();
$table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('customers');
```

Comment: I used to tried $table->foreignIdFor(Customer::class); but it not create the relationship on PHPMyAdmin. But when I tried your answer it works. Really save my life. God bless you

Comment: @user20269367 please reffer laravel documentaion properly. you can solve these kind of issues easily. very happy to helped you